# Unittesting a ServiceStack service that uses AutoMapper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, servicestack

We are using ServiceStack for our .NET backend and I am trying to work on getting unit testing into the project. However there are some automated tools within ServiceStack that makes it a bit complicated to isolate the units so I could really use some advice. In the example below I would like to unit test a simple service that basically does the following:

1. Takes a request DTO
2. Passes the DTO to the repository
3. Gets back a domain model
4. If the model exists, it maps it to a responseDTO using Automapper and returns it as a part of an IHTTPResult

So the problem I have is that it seems like Automapper is automatically added to the ServiceStack application and in the application the mapper are registered by just calling:

```
AutoMapping.RegisterConverter().
```

So how could I inject this into the service to be able to do the unittest?

Example test:

```
using AutoMapper;
using FluentAssertions;
using NSubstitute;

namespace Api.Services.Tests.Unit;

public class OrderApiServiceTests
{
    private readonly OrderApiService _sut;
    private readonly IOrderApiRepository accountApiRepository = Substitute.For<IOrderApiRepository>();

    public OrderApiServiceTests()
    {
        _sut = new OrderApiRepository(orderApiRepository);
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => ApiDtoMapping.Register());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_ShouldReturnAccount_WhenAccountExistsAsync()
    {
        // Arrange
        var order = new Order
        {
            Name = "MyOrder",
            Value = 1000,
        };

        var expectedResponse = new OrderApiDto
        {
            Name = "MyOrder",
            Value = 1000,
        };

        orderApiRepository.GetAsync(Arg.Any<GetOrder>()).Returns(order);

        // Act
        var result = await _sut.Get(new GetOrder());

        // Assert
        result.StatusCode.Should().Be(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Response.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResponse);
    }
}
```

Added a full example including all files:

```
// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}

app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());
app.Run();

// Configure.AppHost.cs
using Funq;
using ssUnitTests.ServiceInterface;

[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(ssUnitTests.AppHost))]

namespace ssUnitTests;

public class AppHost : AppHostBase, IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) => builder
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
        });

    public AppHost() : base("ssUnitTests", typeof(MyServices).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<OrderRepository, IOrderRepository>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);

        // Configure ServiceStack only IOC, Config & Plugins
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            UseSameSiteCookies = true,
        });

        Mappings.RegisterConverters();
    }
}

// Mappings.cs
using ssUnitTests.ServiceModel;

namespace ssUnitTests;

public static class Mappings
{
    public static void RegisterConverters()
    {
        AutoMapping.RegisterConverter((Order from) =>
        {
            var to = from.ConvertTo<OrderDto>();
            to.DtoProperty = from.BaseProperty + "Dto";
            return to;
        });
    }
}

// IOrderRepository.cs
using ssUnitTests.ServiceModel;

namespace ssUnitTests.ServiceInterface;

public interface IOrderRepository
{
    Order GetOrder();
}

// Order.cs
namespace ssUnitTests.ServiceModel;

public class Order
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

// OrderDto.cs
namespace ssUnitTests.ServiceModel;

public class OrderDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DtoProperty { get; set; }
}

// OrderRequest.cs
using ServiceStack;

namespace ssUnitTests.ServiceModel;

[Route("/order")]
public class OrderRequest : IReturn<OrderDto>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

// UnitTest.cs
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ssUnitTests.ServiceInterface;
using ssUnitTests.ServiceModel;

namespace ssUnitTests.Tests;

public class UnitTest
{
    private readonly MyServices _sut;
    private readonly IOrderRepository _repository = Substitute.For<IOrderRepository>();

    public UnitTest()
    {
        _sut = new MyServices(_repository);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_ShouldReturn_OrderDto()
    {
        var order = new Order
        {
            Name = "MyName",
            BaseProperty = "MyBaseProperty"
        };

        _repository.GetOrder().Returns(order);

        var response = (OrderDto)_sut.Any(new OrderRequest { Id = 1 });

        Assert.That(response.Name.Equals(order.Name));
        Assert.That(response.DtoProperty.Equals(order.BaseProperty + "Dto"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServiceStack.dll` does not have any dependencies to any 3rd Party Libraries, e.g. it's [built-in AutoMapping](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) is a completely different stand-alone implementation to [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

If you're using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) you can ignore ServiceStack's AutoMapping which is completely unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for response mythz. Ok I thought ServiceStack were using a customized version of  Automapper, my misstake! No we are using the built in Automapping in ServiceStack. So how would I unit test the service then and just reuse the mapping configuration used for mapping the domain order to a dtoorder?

Comment: I don't see any mapping configuration? If you have any custom converters or populators registered you'd also need to run them in your tests.

Comment: I have updated the original post with a full example since only my unit test was a bit limited to understand the context.

Basically I would like to test the methods of a service in isolation from the rest of the application. Typically if this would been using some other mapping tool then I would expect to be able to abstract and inject it. But how is that suppose to work with ServiceStack?
The result in the test above is that the response.DtoProperty is null since it could not automatically find a property with the same name.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just re-register the same converters that your Application does in your tests so it's running the same exact registrations your App does? Either way you can call `AutoMappingUtils.Reset()` to clear any existing AutoMapping registrations before each fixture.

Comment: I do not understand how I would register the mappings in the test? Do I have to have an apphost to be able to register it?

Comment: Like any other functionality that you share between AppHosts & Tests, e.g. put it in a shared class that you call from both.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I should only need to call the         AutoMapping.RegisterConverter() method from the unit test without rolling up any apphost or similar? Well I tried calling the shared class and also tries to register the converter in place in the unit test. When I do I get a bad crash when it tries to do the conversion: The program '[3928] testhost.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Using the same AppHost isn't required, simply tests that makes usage of the AutoMapping registrations, will need to have them registered before running the tests. I wont be able to tell what's causing the Access violation from here.

Comment: You are writing: -"Using the same AppHost isn't required". Does that mean that any apphost is required?

Comment: [Integration Tests](https://docs.servicestack.net/testing) require an AppHost, [Unit Tests](https://docs.servicestack.net/testing#unit-testing) can use an empty BasicAppHost or if your Services don't make use of any AppHost features you can [manually inject dependencies](https://docs.servicestack.net/testing#manually-injecting-dependencies) and call the service methods directly.